To calibrate model volatility, why does one-factor Hull-White Model not just use implied volatility from Swaptions?
For Swaptions of various expiry/tenor combinations, market (implied) volatilities are readily available. For Swaptions with missing expiry/tenor combinations, their market volatilities are linearly interpolated according to Hull, J., & White, A. (2001). The general Hull–White model and supercalibration. Financial Analysts Journal, 57(6), 34-43. Why would an analyst not just plug in the market (implied) volatilities into the equation? Thank you so much! 

It is not the same type of volatility. The typical Black implied volatilities are lognormal volatilities.
Even if you used implied so called Bachelier normal volatilities you would be wrong. The underlying model is not the same and implied volatilites for a specific expiry is different from the instantaneous volatilities used in the Hull-White process.

Thank you so much Jesper! Hull, J., & White, A. (2001) suggest model volatilities are calculated to minimize the differences between model prices and market prices for benchmark Swaptions ("Specifically we...find the set of volatility parameters that minimizes the sum of the squares of the differences between the model prices and market prices for these options.") If Black implied volatilities are used in the model, then we would expect a perfect match between these prices, so the sum of the squares of the differences will always be minimized at 0, right?

Yes, a typical way to calibrate the Hull-White model is to use market prices for Swaptions (or/and Caps and Floors) where we try to minimize the sum of square difference between market and model prices.
However, you should not expect the match to be perfect. Market prices typically have a so called smile. The implied volatility is different for different option strikes. You don't have enough freedom in the HW model to accommodate for that.
